# Privately sharing web maps with clients

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, security, password, link

Goal: to share a web map (*ideally* created on ArcGIS Online) with clients that do not have an ArcGIS Online (AGOL) account, via a private link or password-protected page.

Research Findings:

- It is NOT possible to remove/"unlist" public AGOL maps from search results.
- AGOL maps must be made public in order to embed them in a website.
- It IS possible to protect the layers from being downloaded.

My current action plan (if nothing better is proposed) is to use map names and tags that do NOT include any identifying information (so that they cannot be searched by the public), and to disable layer downloads.

Also - I am open to third-party options in which we can upload our data to another interactive online map creator that allows for private link sharing.

Comment: Create a group and configure the group settings 'sharing group for data collaboration" https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/sharing-collaboration/sharing-and-collaboration-across-arcgis-online-organizations/

Comment: When I want to do this, I generate an OpenLayers map and install it on my own web server.  Then I can password protect that part of the web server (both the pages, and the data that supplies the map).  I have developed my own OpenLayers map generator (it's an iOS app).  But surely there must be other similar web map generating tools out there?  (I haven't looked.)  Or if you don't mind a bit of JavaScript and want to learn, building an OpenLayers (or Leaflet?) web map manually is not terribly difficult.  Just a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: ...you may also want to set up a GeoServer to serve out the data as web layers that can be consumed by the web map.  Or just use GeoServer on its own - it has some (VERY basic web mapping capabilites built in - based on OpenLayers).  Of course you'd need your own internet web server and/or GeoServer to run all this on.

Comment: Also, just noticed Geonode mentioned in an answer to another question.  I don't know much about it, but it may do what you need.  See:  https://geonode.org

Comment: @Mapperz - thank you very much, but this will only work if the client has an ArcGIS Online (AGOL) account.  I'm trying to find a solution for when the client does NOT have an AGOL account.

Comment: @SonofaBeach - thank you so much for your detailed suggestions! Your method sounds quite intimidating to me... but I can try to figure it out.  Wish me luck!